# Replace repeating character with another repeated character

Tags: regex, r

I would like to replace 3 or more consecutive 0s in a string by consecutive 1s. Example: '1001000001' becomes '1001111111'.

In R, I wrote the following code:

```
gsub("0{3,}","1",reporting_line_string)
```

but obviously it replaces the 5 0s by a single 1. How can I get 5 1s ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `gsubfn` function, which you can supply a replacement function to replace the content matched by the regex.

```
require(gsubfn)
gsubfn("0{3,}", function (x) paste(replicate(nchar(x), "1"), collapse=""), input)
```

You can replace `paste(replicate(nchar(x), "1"), collapse="")` with `stri_dup("1", nchar(x))` if you have `stringi` package installed.

Or a more concise solution, as [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck) suggested in the comment:

```
gsubfn("0{3,}", ~ gsub(".", 1, x), input)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the following regex in Perl mode to replace:

```
gsub("(?!\\A)\\G0|(?=0{3,})0", "1", input, perl=TRUE)
```

It is extensible to any number of consecutive `0` by changing the `0{3,}` part.

I personally don't endorse the use of this solution, though, since it is less maintainable.

Comment: Also try: `gsubfn("0{3,}", ~ gsub(".", 1, x), input)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option that builds on your approach, but makes use of `gregexpr` and `regmatches`. There's probably a more DRY way to do this, but it's not coming to my mind right now....

```
x <- c("1001000001", "120000siw22000100")
x
# [1] "1001000001"        "120000siw22000100"
a <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("0{3,}", x))
regmatches(x, gregexpr("0{3,}", x)) <- lapply(a, function(x) gsub("0", "1", x))
x
# [1] "1001111111"        "121111siw22111100"
```

Answer (score 1):

For `regex` ignorants (like me), try some brute force. Split the string into single characters using `strsplit`, find consecutive runs of "0" using `rle`, create a vector of relevant indices (run lengths of "0" > 2) using `rep`, insert a "1" at the indices, `paste` to a single string.

```
x2 <- strsplit(x = "1001000001", split = "")[[1]]
r <- rle(x2 == "0")
idx <- rep(x = r$lengths > 2, times = r$lengths)
x2[idx] <- "1"
paste(x2, collapse = "")
# [1] "1001111111"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0(?=00)|(?<=00)0|(?<=0)0(?=0)
```

You can try this.Replace by `1`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dP9rO4/5