# Replace a capture group with repeats a single character while retaining the length of the capture group

Tags: regex, r

Suppose you want to replace `AXA` with `AAA`, but also `AXXXXXA` with `AAAAAAA`.

Basically any number of `X` characters between two `A`s with the appropriate number of `A`s.

Using `gsub()` I tried:

```
gsub(x = "AXA", pattern = "(A)(X+)(\\1)", replacement = "\\1\\1\\1")
```

which gives `AAA`. However, it is `AAA` no matter how long `X+` gets. How can I access the length of Subgroup 2 in the output?

Possible duplicate to this:
 [Replace repeating character with another repeated character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650634/replace-repeating-character-with-another-repeated-character)

But IMHO sufficiently different for a separate question.

Comment: this `X` character means any character or specifically `X` ?

Comment: X is an example for the character to be replaced. Can be any character, but it is not changing across the file.

Comment: So `X` is always the same character within the file?

Comment: and starting and ending of strings should be literally `A` or this also can be any character ?

Comment: X or N or 0, doesnt matter, also A can be changed to whatever, but note that we need the subgroup 1 to define the beginning and end of the replacement. The final output should be of the same length as the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a fixed replacement pattern: you captrure `A` in the first group, so, `\\1` refers to `A`. Thus, you get 3 As. You need a different approach: replace all consecutive `X` before `A` and after `A`. It is possible with Perl-style regex:

```
input = "AXXXA"
gsub("(?:A|(?<!^)\\G)\\KX(?=X*A)", "A", input, perl=TRUE)
```

Output of the [demo code](https://ideone.com/itEXvk):

```
[1] "AAAAA"
```

`\G` forces a consecutive match, and `\K` helps us cut off the initially matched `A`. The `(?=X*A)` look-ahead makes sure we have any number of `X` before `A`.

*EDIT:*

This approach works with longer strings, too ([here](https://ideone.com/w3WJvr), we are replacing each `Xyz` between `123` with `A`):

```
input = "123XyzXyzXyz123"
gsub("(?:123|(?<!^)\\G)\\KXyz(?=(?:Xyz)*123)", "A", input, perl=TRUE)
```

Output: `[1] "123AAA123"`

*EDIT 2:*

To replace *any letters* between 2 `A`s we can use `\p{L}` shorthand character class to match any letter before `A`:

```
gsub("(?:A|(?<!^)\\G)\\K\\p{L}(?=\\p{L}*A)", "A", input, perl=TRUE)
=> [1] "XSDFAAAAAA"
```

Comment: @zx8754: How exactly didn't that work? Could you explain the tests? I do not see any issue [here](https://ideone.com/Ylx8oV): `gsub("(?:A|(?<!^)\\G)\\K\\p{L}(?=\\p{L}*A)", "A", input, perl=TRUE)` => `[1] "XSDFAAAAAA"` The pattern instead of `X` can be any, the approach is working.

Comment: OK, `EDIT 2` version works. I upvoted already, just wanted to request to make the solution more robust, thanks.